# T-SQL Create User/Login not allowing connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a basic, plain-text password login and database user for a locally running instance of SQL Server 2008.  I'm using the following SQL code to make the logins, add the user, and give permissions, but I cannot connect to the server with SSMS or SQLCMD (which works fine when I use my domain credentials and Integrated Security).

```
 USE <database_name>
 GO
 CREATE LOGIN aspLogin with password=N'pass1',
DEFAULT_DATABASE=<default_db>, CHECK_POLICY = OFF
 GO
 CREATE USER aspLogin FOR LOGIN aspLogin
 EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'aspLogin'
 EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'aspLogin'
 GO
 USE master
 GO
 GRANT CONNECT SQL TO aspLogin
```

Using SQLCMD:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S .\SQL -P pass1 -U aspLogin
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server <machine_name>\SQL, Line 1
Login failed for user 'aspLogin'.
```

What am I missing?  Is this a problem with using ".\SQL" (which is the correct name of the instance, not the default instance name).  For example, this works fine:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S .\SQL -E
1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure mixed mode authentication is enabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.105).aspx

You can easily check the authentication mode using

```
exec master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'
```